# Iterating through EditItemTemplate textboxes in asp:Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview displaying data within a template field which requires more information about the record to be displayed by clicking on a linkbutton. Right now, I have the "details" linkbutton display the information by calling the edit command on the gridview so that it switches to the EditItemTemplate. Within the EditItemTemplate I have a linkbutton for cancel and then an edit button that, when clicked, displays the update button with the update command, but I need it to iterate through that row and set all the textboxes within the EditItemTemplate to ReadOnly=false so as to allow them to be edited before the update command is selected. Here is a summary of the code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    *basic information displayed*
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Details"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    *A bunch of readonly textboxes that display the extra information*
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" Visible="false"></asp:LinkButton> 
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="editButton_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

And the code for the event which makes the buttons appear the way I want, but I'm not sure how to iterate through the EditItemTemplate, or even if this is what I should do:

```
 Protected Sub editButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        sender.FindControl("updateButton").Visible = True
        sender.FindControl("editbutton").Visible = False
        For Each t In ?EditItemTemplate?
            Dim textbox = TryCast(t, System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)
            If textbox IsNot Nothing Then
                textbox.ReadOnly = False
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

So my question is either how to get this to work, or how I should set up the GridViewCommands otherwise

Comment: Perhaps utilizing the default mechanism GridView provides will make more sense. Have an item template and an edit template for each of the columns that needs to be editable, and just fire "Edit" command with Edit button. That way corresponding row in GridView will render each column using the edit template, which is exactly what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out how to do it (needed it in vb) by using the placeholder within the EditItemTemplate, here's the code behind it:

```
Protected Sub editButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    sender.FindControl("editbutton").Visible = False
    sender.FindControl("updateButton").Visible = True

    Dim testPlacehldr As PlaceHolder = sender.FindControl("TestPlaceholder")
    If testPlacehldr.Controls.Count > 0 Then
        Dim btn As LinkButton = sender.FindControl("editButton")
        If btn.Visible = False Then
            For Each ctrl As Control In testPlacehldr.Controls
                If ctrl.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) Then
                    Dim box As TextBox = TryCast(ctrl, TextBox)
                    box.ReadOnly = False
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This works fine for what I need it to do. Credit to the user R.C. for the idea about placeholders

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [**`PlaceHolder`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your `EditItemTemplate`. Place all of your Controls/LinkButtons inside this placeholder.

```
<EditItemTemplate>

<asp:PlaceHolder ID="TestPlaceHolder" runat="server">

// Sample Link Buttons
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"
         Visible="false"></asp:LinkButton> 
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="editButton_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
// Sample Text Box
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="FirstName" ...>...</TextBox>

</asp:PlaceHolder>

</EditItemTemplate>
```

Handle the [**`RowEditing`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of GridView. Inside the edit event handler, first find the Placeholder, then use the [**`PlaceHolder's Controls`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to iterate over the Controls...

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
  {
     // Get the Placeholder for the row being edited.  
        PlaceHolder testPlacehldr =
        GridView.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("TestPlaceholder") as PlaceHolder;
       // Iterate over the controls
         if(testPlacehldr.Controls.Count > 0)
             {    
                foreach (Control ctrl in testPlacehldr.Controls)
                   {
                       if (ctrl is LinkButton)
                           { 
                              LinkButton lnkBtn = ctrl as LinkButton
                                if(lnkBtn.Text== "Update")
                                  {
                                    lnkBtn.Visible = false;
                                  }
                                // More IF conditions follow....
                           }

                   if (ctrl is TextBox)
                       { 
                        TextBox txtBox = ctrl as TextBox;
                        if(txtBox.ID == "FirstName")// use any property of TexBox you prefer
                                  {
                                    txtBox.ReadOnly= true;
                                  }
                           // More IF conditions follow....
                          }
                   }    
             }         
        //At the End, set the EditIndex and Bind the data
          GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
          BindGridViewData();
   }
```

I hope you can workout the logic yourself now for hiding/showing the controls.

Comment: The placeholder definitely helps, my own question would be how to reiterate through those controls on the editbutton click so as to make the textboxes appear as writable. Can you call the GridViewEditEventArgs from a button click event? How?